# Superposition of a Poisson process with another

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes

Find the probability density function of the superposition of a Poisson process with a sequence of observed random variables $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ that are generated according to another Poisson process? ASSUME ALL ARE INDEPENDENT.

I am really unsure how to solve this

Comment: What is the relationship of 'another' Poisson process to the three already mentioned?

Comment: @bruceet see edited priblem please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comment:** The question seems strangely worded and I am still not exactly
sure what you are being asked to do. Here is what I can make of it.

If $U \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda_u)$ and, independently,  $V \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda_v),$ then a 'superposition' of these two processes
yields Poisson process $X = U+V$ with parameter $\mathsf{\lambda_x = \lambda_u + \lambda_v}.$

If you have independent observations $X_i$ from the combined process,
you can estimate $\lambda_x$ as $\hat \lambda = \bar X,$ but you cannot
find $\lambda_x$ *exactly.* And with just this information, you cannot
estimate $\lambda_u$ or $\lambda_v.$ This raises the question in my mind
why $U$ and $V$ and the mechanism of superposition were mentioned.

---

If you use $\hat \lambda_x = \bar X_{100}$ based on $n = 100$ observations $X_i$ then $E(\hat\lambda_x) = \lambda_x$ and $SD(\hat \lambda_x) = 
\sqrt{\lambda_x/100}.$ Also the distribution of $\hat \lambda_s$ for
such a large $n$ is nearly normal, provided that $\lambda_x$ is of moderate
or large size.

Comment: Thanks. Although this was not what I meant, it was really helpful. Here I have posted the new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473568/superposition-of-a-poisson-process-with-a-vector